# Changing the value of a cell when all cells in a range equal the same value

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to create a macro to change the value of a single cell only when all cells in a range are of a specific value.
I’ve looked around and it seems I can only do this with a worksheet change macro based on a variant.
Based on this, I have put together the following:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change() 

Dim VarItemName As Variant
VarItemName = Range("Other_Checks!G85:G87")
Dim Value As String

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Range("Other_Checks!G85, Other_Checks!G86, Other_Checks!G87").Value = "N/A" Then
    Range("Other_Checks!G88").Value = "N/A"
Else
    Range("Other_Checks!G88").Value = "Pending"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

The problem is it only seems to work if the first cell in the range (G85) changes (regardless of the value of the other 2 cells).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so you want to maybe put the cell values into an array and check them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me using the `Worksheet_Change` event.

You'll need to substitute your range references.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim VarItemName As Range, cl As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C1")) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("A1") = "n/a" And Range("B1") = "n/a" And Range("C1") = "n/a" Then
            Range("A2") = "n/a"
        Else
            Range("A2") = "Pending"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

By the way, this could easily be done using an `IF` formula on the spreadsheet. It may be an option to consider?

Comment: thank you for your reply, your assistance is very much appreciated. unfortunately, this is not working for me at all. I've edited the ranges as you suggested but the target cell remains unchanged when the range matches my requirements. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: a) Are you putting the code in the `Worksheet_Change` event i.e. not manually typing it into a module but putting it into the `Sheet` code? b) You haven't got `recalc` set to manual?

Comment: Ah, that was my problem. I had it in a module. I've moved it into the sheet code and it now works perfectly. Thank you very much. You, sir, are a legend!